# sympy dsolve returns valueerror on number of arguments

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have a system of 4 differential equations that are the result of some electrical circuit mesh analysis.
And my equations are:

```
i1 = Function('i1')
i2 = Function('i2')
i3 = Function('i3')
i4 = Function('i4')
t = symbols('t')

eq1 = diff(i1(t))+ integrate(i1(t)-i2(t), t) 
eq5 = diff(eq1,t)
eq2 = -integrate(i1(t)-i2(t), t) + (i2(t) - i3(t)) + integrate(i2(t)-i3(t), t)
eq6 = diff(eq2,t)
eq3 = -integrate(i2(t)-i3(t), t) - (i2(t)-i3(t)) + diff(i3(t),t) +integrate(i3(t)-i4(t), t)  
eq7 = diff(eq3, t)
eq4 = -integrate(i3(t)-i4(t), t)  +i4(t)
eq8= diff(eq4,t)
```

`dsolve` is giving me a `MatrixError`, when used like:
`dsolve([eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8])`
`Jordan normal form is not implemented if the matrix have eigenvalues in CRootOf form`
So I guess I'll have to try numerically?

Comment: Your equations are integro-differential equations. The `dsolve` function is for ODEs.

Comment: Do I also need to organize or collect terms in the equations? I purposefully left them as written from hand analysis, thinking sympy would be able to put them in the proper form.

Comment: After differentiating the equations (and also fixing a sign/polarity mistake in my equations, I now get a `MatrixError`. Also, if I supply the `func` keyword argument, is returns a `TypeError` on them. So I still feel like my problem is ill-formed.

Comment: You have changed this since before and removed all of the symbols from the equations. In this new form it is something that in principle could be solved analytically although this particular case is not quite yet supported in sympy. The eigenvectors routine can handle this case but the Jordan normal form routine can not yet (even though they both compute the same thing). Your original equations would most likely not have a usable analytic solution due to the symbols involved and the Abel-Ruffini theorem.